# Refreshing content in jcombo box java using database

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing, jcombobox

Is it possible to have content refresh in one combo box after selecting an item in the first combo box. The items in the first combo box would be the types and the second combo box would have that items sub types. In addition, this would have to happen on one frame. The data in the combo box would be read from a database. The types would be a column in the database and so would the sub-types. The database i am using is MYSQL.

Any suggestions for quick easy code?

i have a really good image for illustrating this question, but i need more rep to add it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- use [XxxComboBoxModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ComboBoxModel.html) for storing Items for [JComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)
- [all updates to the JComboBox and its XxxComboBoxModel must be done on EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)
- invoke `Database` event from the `Runnable#Thread` or `SwingWorker`, redirect this (potentionally) hard and long running task to the `Workers Thread`, otherwise Swing GUi will be freeze or unresponsive (for mouse and key events) untill JDBC ended
- [`SwingWorker`s methods publish(), process() and done()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html) quite good quaranteed that all output wil be done on EDT

for example

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ComboBoxTwo extends JFrame implements ActionListener, ItemListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JComboBox mainComboBox;
    private JComboBox subComboBox;
    private Hashtable<Object, Object> subItems = new Hashtable<Object, Object>();

    public ComboBoxTwo() {
        String[] items = {"Select Item", "Color", "Shape", "Fruit"};
        mainComboBox = new JComboBox(items);
        mainComboBox.addActionListener(this);
        mainComboBox.addItemListener(this);
        //prevent action events from being fired when the up/down arrow keys are used
        //mainComboBox.putClientProperty("JComboBox.isTableCellEditor", Boolean.TRUE);
        getContentPane().add(mainComboBox, BorderLayout.WEST);
        subComboBox = new JComboBox();//  Create sub combo box with multiple models
        subComboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("XXXXXXXXXX"); // JDK1.4
        subComboBox.addItemListener(this);
        getContentPane().add(subComboBox, BorderLayout.EAST);
        String[] subItems1 = {"Select Color", "Red", "Blue", "Green"};
        subItems.put(items[1], subItems1);
        String[] subItems2 = {"Select Shape", "Circle", "Square", "Triangle"};
        subItems.put(items[2], subItems2);
        String[] subItems3 = {"Select Fruit", "Apple", "Orange", "Banana"};
        subItems.put(items[3], subItems3);
//      mainComboBox.setSelectedIndex(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String item = (String) mainComboBox.getSelectedItem();
        Object o = subItems.get(item);
        if (o == null) {
            subComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel());
        } else {
            subComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel((String[]) o));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            if (e.getSource() == mainComboBox) {
                if (mainComboBox.getSelectedIndex() != 0) {
                    FirstDialog firstDialog = new FirstDialog(ComboBoxTwo.this,
                            mainComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString(), "Please wait,  Searching for ..... ");
                }
            } 
        }
    }

    private class FirstDialog extends JDialog { //sipmle simulation of JDBC events, by using Swing Timer

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        FirstDialog(final Frame parent, String winTitle, String msgString) {
            super(parent, winTitle);
            setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            JLabel myLabel = new JLabel(msgString);
            JButton bNext = new JButton("Stop Processes");
            add(myLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            add(bNext, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            bNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    setVisible(false);
                }
            });
            javax.swing.Timer t = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    setVisible(false);
                }
            });
            t.setRepeats(false);
            t.start();
            setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
            setSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
            setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new ComboBoxTwo();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant!! thanks, but one major part i wanted to know was, how would i get the data from the first combo box which is read from the database and read the data from the database fro the second combo box which only applies to the answer selected in the first combo box ? So rather than having an array you filled, you would have the data from the database in that array.